# redirect url to 404 page if the controller or method is not exist

Tags: php, url-routing

I want to redirect the user to the 404 page if the URL contains Controller and Method that not exist

```
<?php

define('WEBROOT',str_replace('index.php','',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
//echo (WEBROOT .'<br/>');
define('ROOT',str_replace('index.php','',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
//echo (ROOT .'<br/>');

require_once(ROOT."core/Controller.php");

$url = $_GET["p"];
$urlArray = array();

$urlArray = explode("/", $url);

$controller = !empty($urlArray[0]) ? $urlArray[0] : "Home";
$methodOrAction = !empty($urlArray[1]) ? $urlArray[1] : "index";

echo $controller ."<br/>";
echo $methodOrAction ."<br/>";


if (file_exists("controllers/".$controller.".php") && method_exists($controller,$methodOrAction)){

    require_once("controllers/".$controller.".php"); 

    $controller = new $controller();

    $controller->$methodOrAction(); 

}else{

    // echo '404 : This file or method is not exist !';

    require_once("controllers/ErrorMsg.php");

    $ErrorMsg = new ErrorMsg();

    $ErrorMsg->DisplayError();

}
```

Comment: I don't see the error here. Can you be more explicit about what you get and what you want to get please?

Comment: Hi , the if() statement not working because when i put in the URL any controller or action that not exist the result is unacceptable

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting someone to a default 404 page is not user-friendly. Instead, you can create an error page and redirect users to that page by:

```
Header("Location: /404.html");
```

This would redirect a visitor to www.yourwebsite.com/404.html. You can customize the link in any way you want.

Comment: thanks but acually i don't want to use header function i want to use redirection as controller as you see in the code

Comment: Well - then you need to be more specific about that. Can you also include more details about the overall structure of your system?